# MobileFirst Server preparation for uploaded log data - Security

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

I am using MobileFirst Server MFPF 7.1, IF20151114-1616

WLClientLogReceiver adapter has the following settings. I tried changing the securityTest value to "LogUploadServlet", I still receive the same error below.

```
<procedure name="log" securityTest="wl_unprotected" audit="true" />
```

To enable security that protects the loguploader servlet, I followed the instruction given in the IBM document on step one.

[Server preparation for uploaded log data - Security](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_uploaded_client_log_data.html)

Configuration in my aunthenticationConfig.xml

Under staticResources

```
<resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet">
    <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns>
</resource>
```

Under securityTests

```
<customSecurityTest name="LogUploadServlet">
    <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/>
    <test realm="LogUploadServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

Under realms

```
<realm name="LogUploadServlet" loginModule="StrongDummy">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
</realm>
```

Deployed the updated WAR file and adapter in server. I am receiving the below error while client send logs to server by calling send() method.

> [2/12/16 14:14:28:768 CST] 0000014d LoginContext  W com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext invokeLoginModule FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'LogUploadServlet': Please check the credentials [project usbusiness]
>   [2/12/16 14:14:28:933 CST] 000000d1 LoginContext  W com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext invokeLoginModule FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'LogUploadServlet': Please check the credentials [project usbusiness]
>   [2/12/16 14:14:30:542 CST] 000000de SystemOut

Not sure what i a missing in this.

Comment: Hi PVR, I am investigating this issue and I would like to try to narrow the scope of this issue down a bit. I do not think the issue has to deal with with your WLClientLogReceiver adapter. I am going to start to look into protecting the apps/services/loguploader/* URI.

Comment: However, on the WLClientLogReceiver I do not think you need a security test. Security test are generally used for if your client obtaining sensitive information. This adapter is used to send client logs FROM the worklight server to a destination of your choice. This procedure is only invoked by the worklight server (unless of course you invoke it on the client). By placing a security test on this procedure you are asking your worklight server to authenticate against itself to send logs. I can confirm with our security team but I believe if you protect this adapter you will encounter issues.

Comment: For protecting the URI "apps/services/loguploader/*" did you choose option 1 or 2 from knowledge center?
Option 1: Use a security test that requires no custom challenge handler code and no user interaction, and freely call the logger send function.
Option 2: Ensure that the security test in front of the servlet remains the same as the security test of the application, and be careful about placement of extra logger send function calls.

Comment: I see from the post you mention you are using option one. Disregard my last comment.

Comment: HI Chevy, Thanks. I missed updating this post. Issue is with the realm com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator that I set for logUploadServlet. after removing and make the security as  isInternalUserID="true" its working fine.

Comment: What class did you end up using in your realm to get this to work? Also, could you provide your answer below and mark it as correct?

Comment: what did you change your realm to to get this to work?

Comment: @PVR please do not leave questions unanswered - write a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not leave a question unanswered, from the comments section:

> Issue is with the realm com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator that I set for logUploadServlet. after removing and make the security as isInternalUserID="true" its working fine.